# How can I patch the Stripe Subscription

Tags: python, testing, mocking, patch

I'm writing tests for module which using Stripe for payment. And I'd like to make a mock for it to don't send queries to API.
I use the next code for it, but still I have queries to API. I don't understand why? Such query appears at the Stripe log every time I'm running the test:

```
/v1/customers/cus_*********/subscription
```

There is my code:

```
@patch('stripe.Subscription.save')
def test_subscription(self, subscription_update):
    subscription_update.return_value = self.convert_to_stripe_object({...})
    # there is test code
```

What's the cause of this and how can I patch that query? Thanks for any help!

Comment: `
    @patch('stripe.Plan.list')
    @patch('stripe.Customer.save')
    @patch('stripe.Customer.create')
    @patch('stripe.Token.create')
    @patch('stripe.Customer.delete')
    @patch('stripe.Plan.create')
    @patch('stripe.Plan.delete')
`
I use all of above methods for patching and it works properly as described at the documentation. It's weird, but I can't to find needed option here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I patched update_subscription function:

```
@mock.patch.object(stripe.Customer, 'update_subscription', autospec=True)
```